# Error inserting code after a break

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

It's gives me error after break in the second if sequence.

```
int value;
value=someMethod();
foreach(List<GameObject>lista in tilesOrganizadosPorColuna)
{
    bool found=false; 
      //DoSomething(); 
    if(value==1)
    {  
    //if value=1 do just first iteration.
    break; 
   }
}

if(!found)
//DoOtherThhink();
}
```

What's the correct way to do it? (I want to stop the foreach loop not the if)Thanks. I tryed google, but that was the example that I found. (That a break inside if would stop foreach not just the if).

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: So is the error in DoSomething()?

Comment: Take a close look at your code.. where is the second `}` in the if statement.. please clean up the code and format it correctly.. google will not help you in debugging you need to use the debugger to step through the existing code.. also where are you using lista...??
`int value;
value=...;
foreach(List<GameObject>lista in tilesOrganizadosPorColuna){
bool finded=false; ` please show all full and relevant code.. `value = ...` does nobody any good.. also what is finded being used for.

Comment: `second if sequence` You don't show any code in that second `if` or even tell us what the error is to begin with. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: I wrote here incorrectly, but in the code was okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of indentation makes this hard to read, but I figure you meant to do this:

```
bool found=false; 
int value;
value=...;

foreach(List<GameObject>lista in tilesOrganizadosPorColuna)
{
    if(value==1)
    {   
        found=true;
        break; 
    }
}

if(!found)
{
    //DoSomething()
}
```

You were missing a couple of brackets. I figure your IDE should have warned you of this.

I'm afraid your code doesn't make a whole lot of sense though, since you're not doing anything with what you're iterating, so `found` will only be dependant on what `value` is initialized to.

Comment: Good point. I forgot C# worked like that. Edited answer.